# Servlet ClassNotFoundException when present in a package ... Why?

Tags: java, servlets, classnotfoundexception

When i am keeping the "MyServletProgram" in "java" package i get ClassNotFoundException java.MyServletProgram but when it is in default package, the program runs fine. Can you suggest where i am going wrong??

[image: This is Servlet class]

[image: This is the project heirarchy]

[image: This is the navigator view of project]

[image: My classpaths]

[image: The error when accessing through /MyServletProgram]

Comment: Maybe problem with Naming conventions.
`java` is already defined Package, change your Package name and it will work.

Comment: The java namespace is reserved for JavaSE standard classes not for your own. I suspect this is your problem. The namespace system in java is designed to prevent conflicts by using your own registered domain name, reversed, as a base package for you to include your packages inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not name a package as `java` , since it is prohibited

You are likely to get an exception :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java
```

Change you `package` name to something else and it will work flawlessly .